# How to delete a row from a SQL Server CE Table?

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-ce

I want to delete a record from a SQL Server CE table.

There are 3 tables scripts, options and results. I would like to remove a record from the results table. The where clause contains dynamic information which retrieved via other queries. These queries work fine and deliver the desired data.

The error I get is:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 25,Token in error = from ]

The code that throws the exception is as follows:

```
Dim connLoc As SqlCeConnection = New SqlCeConnection(My.Settings.ConnectionString)
connLoc.Open()     
Dim strDel As String = "Delete ResultsTable from ResultsTable r inner join OptionsTable o ON o.TestName=r.TestName inner join ScriptTable c ON r.TestName=c.TestName WHERE r.TestName = '" & ds1Loc.Tables(0).Rows(0)(1) & "' AND [Index] = '" & lstIndex & "'"
Dim cmdDel As SqlCeCommand = New SqlCeCommand
cmdDel.CommandText = strDel
cmdDel.Connection = connLoc
cmdDel.ExecuteScalar()
```

The values held in `ds1Loc.Tables(0).Rows(0)(1)` and `lstIndex` are correct so should not be the problem.

Also this query works with SQL Server. Is it perhaps that SQL CE does not support the Delete function the same as SQL Server 2008?

**EDIT**

Using Kafs suggested solution below the exception is still the same:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token
>   line offset = 10,Token in error = from ]

The commandText of cmdDel before execution is

```
Delete r from ResultsTable r inner join OptionsTable o ON o.TestName=r.TestName inner join ScriptTable c ON r.TestName=c.TestName WHERE r.TestName = @TestName AND [Index] = @lstIndex
```

`@TestName` and `@lstIndex` have values of 'My test' and '3' respectivley.

It may be worth mentioning for anyone reading this in future that I changed 'SQLParameter' to SQLCeParameter as this query is going to a SQL CE Server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Table alies` (r) which you have given for `ResultsTable` correctly as;

```
//--Correct way
Dim strDel As String = "Delete r from ResultsTable r ..."

//--Following is wrong
Dim strDel As String = "Delete ResultsTable from ResultsTable r ..."
```

Also it is better to use a `Parameterized query`  rather than passing strings then `ExecuteNonQuery()` and `Close()` the connection at the end

```
Dim strDel As String = "Delete r from ResultsTable r inner join OptionsTable o
                         ON o.TestName=r.TestName inner join ScriptTable c 
                         ON r.TestName=c.TestName WHERE r.TestName = @TestName 
                         AND [Index] = @LastIndex"

With cmdDel.Parameters
        .Add(New SqlParameter("@TestName", ds1Loc.Tables(0).Rows(0)(1)))
        .Add(New SqlParameter("@LastIndex", lstIndex))
End With
...
cmdDel.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am still getting an exception, slightly different this time : 'There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 10,Token in error = from ].'

Comment: I have updated the answer with more details. can you show what you have in `strDel` string before the execution.

Comment: Thanks again, unfortunately the exception remains the same. I have updated my original question with the details after trying your edited soultion as it is easier to read there and also I cannot have multiple "@" symbols in a comment box.

Comment: did you try to `cmdDel.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead `cmdDel.ExecuteScalar()`?

Comment: Yes, I tried most of the execute statements. I really am stumped. SQL CE supports deletes the same as SQL Server, I presume?

Comment: Even though it does not matter as long as tables are in the database,  I have noted that your two queries have two different set of table names. Can you try to use square brakets with table names as  `"[TableNames]"` to make sure you haven't got `reserved key words` for your table names.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23774/discussion-between-kaf-and-redned)

Comment: Apologies that was lazy copy and pasting on my part. I will edit the names for consistency and reduce any confusion on future views of this question. The square brackets made no difference.